# Custom template with functionality inside Layout component provided by the current route

Tags: angular

I have an Angular layout and it is used by multiple routes. I wanted to know if it is possible to have an area inside it that would be controller by the current route. For example some buttons with specific logic for on click.

Layout:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <div>
    <span class="titleBig">Title</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    /* Here should be the custom template from the current route */
  </div>  
</div>  
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Route 1:

```
<button type='button' mat-button (click)="doMath()">Do Math</button>
```

Route 2:

```
<button type='button' mat-button (click)="doPlayOutside()">Do Play</button>
```

Comment: Already tried [`<ng-content></ng-content>`](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#single-slot-content-projection)?

Comment: @Pieterjan Nope. I was not able to make it work...

Comment: it is a bit cumbersome but you could use named router outlets. Otherwise you'll have to do some shenanigans using activatedRoute and `<ng-template>`

Comment: @Mikkel Christensen I want to avoid multiple router outlets... especially when the content is more complex and very tight with the current route component logic.

Comment: Easiest solution would be to restructure your DOM to allow the unique parts to be part of the template of the routed component.

Comment: @Mikkel Christensen Sure.... would be a solution but in this case it will be to much work... I was looking to a shortcut.

Comment: Either way is going to be a bit of a hack. You could, if you don't have too many routes use a `ngSwitch` and subscribe to url on `activatedRoute.` letting the router-outlet component own the logic for your route context specific actions.

Answer (score 2):

you have two options, add a single button, then modify the button so that it executes based on the route.

html

```
<button type='button' mat-button (click)="multiPurproseButton()">Do Math</button>
```

ts

```
multiPurproseButton() {
  // write some logic to get the path from the url, I am keeping it simple!
  const path = this.router.url.split('/').pop();
  switch(path) {
    case 'home':
       this.doMath();
    case 'about':
       this.doPlayOutside();
  }
}
```

The second option is to use [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) this will render multiple html based on the route you are on.

html

```
<div [ngSwitch]="currentPath">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'home'">
    <h2>Map View Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est minima ipsa ex modi laudantium aliquam dolor expedita, numquam officiis omnis.</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'about'">
    <h2>List View Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium officiis totam debitis? Repellat non a magni mollitia provident, quaerat eum.</p>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>OtherWise</div>
</div>
</div>
```

ts

```
get currentPath() {
  // write some logic to get the path from the url, I am keeping it simple!
  const path = this.router.url.split('/').pop(); 
  return path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort u put to try to help me. The problem is that the logic under each button is done on the current route, so I can't move it into the layout and have multiPurproseButton function to call each of them: doMath(), doPlayOutside(). I will upvote the solution for the effort.

Comment: @DA you can use a subject in a service and emit, then recieve on the child component and perform the action example of subject [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-sample)

Comment: The HTML with buttons was just a simple example to explain my problem. The HTML and the logic from behind is more complex and it is strange that there is no simple choice to inject that HTML in the layout and use the logic from the current route.... knowing that the layout HTML and current route HTML are merged together in DOM...

Comment: @DA Have you checked out the subject emitter pattern I have provided in the comments

Comment: Yes, I know it. But my HTML is rendered from more components on each route. The option with [ngSwitch] or ifs... is not working for me.... how can I inject this complex HTML in Layout. This is in fact the trouble question. The logic with a service as a bus will work in the end but I can't escape this problem.

Comment: @DA There are the options, I dont understand why my solutions don't work

Comment: I can't put ifs for 20 routes and tight their HTML by the layout. My layout will not be a generic one anymore for other routes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247524/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-d-a).